# Docker build jfrog artifactory private feed authentication via environment variable not working

Tags: docker, .net-core, dockerfile, nuget

After going through or referring through alot of documentation and SO threads on using Nuget.config file to restore build process; i give up and here asking for help.

```
>docker info
Client:
 Version:    24.0.6
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
```

My Docker file:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8 AS buildPhase
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
ARG ARTIFACTORY__API_KEY=%ARTIFACTORY__API_KEY%
ARG ARTIFACTORY__USER=%ARTIFACTORY__USER%
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["MyProj/MyProj.csproj", "MyProj/"]
COPY ./Nuget.config /src
RUN dotnet restore "./MyProj/MyProj.csproj" --configfile /src/Nuget.config
```

My Nuget.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>    
    <add key="dev" value="https://xyz.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/nuget/v3/dev-nuget" />
  </packageSources>
  <packageSourceCredentials>
    <dev>
      <add key="Username" value="%ARTIFACTORY__USER%" />
      <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="%ARTIFACTORY__API_KEY%" />
    </dev>
  </packageSourceCredentials>
    <packageSourceMapping>
        <packageSource key="dev">
            <package pattern="*" />
        </packageSource>
    </packageSourceMapping>
</configuration>
```

With above configuration; i am trying to set the environment variables for Nuget feed by following this article: https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/main/documentation/scenarios/nuget-credentials.md#using-environment-variables-in-nugetconfig

No matter what i try (powershell/cmd) i am unable to get the restore phase success in dockerfile.

Below are the commands i am issuing:

```
> $env:ARTIFACTORY__USER = 'user@user.com'
>  $env:ARTIFACTORY__API_KEY = 'apikey'
> docker build --build-arg $env:ARTIFACTORY__API_KEY --build-arg $env:ARTIFACTORY__USER -f .\Custom.Dockerfile .
```

Errors i get are and docker build output:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon    450kB
Step 1/20 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8 AS buildSicamLicenseSigner
 ---> 6232c212dfa2
Step 2/20 : ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 03d673382ea5
Step 3/20 : ARG ARTIFACTORY__API_KEY=%ARTIFACTORY__API_KEY%
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b9a5202d2492
Step 4/20 : ARG ARTIFACTORY__USER=%ARTIFACTORY__USER%
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 24026604c95e
Step 5/20 : WORKDIR /src
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 3026cc959337
Step 6/20 : COPY ["MyProj/MyProj.csproj", "MyProj/"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e4fc943fcd7e
Step 7/20 : COPY ./Nuget.config /src
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b797e8f1b9fd
Step 8/20 : RUN dotnet restore "./MyProj/MyProj.csproj" --configfile /src/Nuget.config
 ---> Running in 0f70aa322b50
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.101\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\Sdk\Sdk.targets(37,3): warning MSB4011: "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.101\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" cannot be imported again. It was already imported at "C:\src\MyProj\MyProj.csproj (85,2)". This is most likely a build authoring error. This subsequent import will be ignored.
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.101\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\Sdk\Sdk.targets(37,3): warning MSB4011: "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.101\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" cannot be imported again. It was already imported at "C:\src\MyProj\MyProj.csproj (85,2)". This is most likely a build authoring error. This subsequent import will be ignored.
  Determining projects to restore...
  Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore' for source 'https://xyz.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/nuget/v3/dev-nuget/FindPackagesById()?id='CommandLineParser'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
  Response status code does not indicate success: 401.
  Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore' for source 'https://xyz.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/nuget/v3/dev-nuget/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
  Response status code does not indicate success: 403.
  Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore' for source 'https://xyz.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/nuget/v3/dev-nuget/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
  Response status code does not indicate success: 401.
  Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore' for source 'https://xyz.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/nuget/v3/dev-nuget/FindPackagesById()?id='ServerClient'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
  Response status code does not indicate success: 401.
  Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore' for source 'https://xyz.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/nuget/v3/dev-nuget/FindPackagesById()?id='Serilog.Settings.Configuration'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
  Response status code does not indicate success: 403.
  Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore' for source 'https://xyz.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/nuget/v3/dev-nuget/FindPackagesById()?id='Serilog.Sinks.File'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
  Response status code does not indicate success: 403.
  Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore' for source 'https://xyz.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/nuget/v3/dev-nuget/FindPackagesById()?id='Serilog'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
  Response status code does not indicate success: 403.
  Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore' for source 'https://xyz.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/nuget/v3/dev-nuget/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
  Response status code does not indicate success: 403.
  Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore' for source 'https://xyz.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/nuget/v3/dev-nuget/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
  Response status code does not indicate success: 403.
  Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore' for source 'https://xyz.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/nuget/v3/dev-nuget/FindPackagesById()?id='ServerClient'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
  Response status code does not indicate success: 403.
  Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore' for source 'https://xyz.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/nuget/v3/dev-nuget/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
  Response status code does not indicate success: 403.
  Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore' for source 'https://xyz.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/nuget/v3/dev-nuget/FindPackagesById()?id='CommandLineParser'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
  Response status code does not indicate success: 403.
  Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore' for source 'https://xyz.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/nuget/v3/dev-nuget/FindPackagesById()?id='Serilog.Settings.Configuration'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
  Response status code does not indicate success: 403.
  Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore' for source 'https://xyz.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/nuget/v3/dev-nuget/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
  Response status code does not indicate success: 403.
  Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore' for source 'https://xyz.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/nuget/v3/dev-nuget/FindPackagesById()?id='Serilog.Sinks.File'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
  Response status code does not indicate success: 403.
  Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore' for source 'https://xyz.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/nuget/v3/dev-nuget/FindPackagesById()?id='Serilog'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
  Response status code does not indicate success: 403.
C:\src\MyProj\MyProj.csproj : error NU1301: Failed to retrieve information about 'ServerClient' from remote source 'https://xyz.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/nuget/v3/dev-nuget/FindPackagesById()?id='ServerClient'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
C:\src\MyProj\MyProj.csproj : error NU1301: Failed to retrieve information about 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration' from remote source 'https://xyz.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/nuget/v3/dev-nuget/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
C:\src\MyProj\MyProj.csproj : error NU1301: Failed to retrieve information about 'Serilog.Settings.Configuration' from remote source 'https://xyz.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/nuget/v3/dev-nuget/FindPackagesById()?id='Serilog.Settings.Configuration'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
C:\src\MyProj\MyProj.csproj : error NU1301: Failed to retrieve information about 'CommandLineParser' from remote source 'https://xyz.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/nuget/v3/dev-nuget/FindPackagesById()?id='CommandLineParser'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
C:\src\MyProj\MyProj.csproj : error NU1301: Failed to retrieve information about 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel' from remote source 'https://xyz.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/nuget/v3/dev-nuget/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
C:\src\MyProj/MyProj.csproj : error NU1301: Failed to retrieve information about 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json' from remote source 'https://xyz.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/nuget/v3/dev-nuget/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
C:\src\MyProj/MyProj.csproj : error NU1301: Failed to retrieve information about 'Serilog.Sinks.File' from remote source 'https://xyz.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/nuget/v3/dev-nuget/FindPackagesById()?id='Serilog.Sinks.File'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
C:\src\MyProj/MyProj.csproj : error NU1301: Failed to retrieve information about 'Serilog' from remote source 'https://xyz.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/nuget/v3/dev-nuget/FindPackagesById()?id='Serilog'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
  Failed to restore C:\src\MyProj\MyProj.csproj (in 4.98 sec).
The command 'powershell -Command $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'; dotnet restore "./MyProj/MyProj.csproj" --configfile /src/Nuget.config' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Note: UserName and Password are valid and working on my local machine whenever i build via CLI/Visual studio. But on docker build it does not work (same information).